# Map or Ignore Indexer Property in Automapper 11

Tags: automapper, automapper-11

I'm having some issues mapping two classes using the AutoMapper in version 11. The destination class has an indexer-property, which causes the issue.

Since Automapper 11, the indexer property is no longer [automatically](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#c-indexers-item-property) ignored.

For testing purposes I used three classes:

```cs
public class Source {}

public class Target {
    public float this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}

public class MapperProfile: Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Target>();
    }
}
```

During startup I'm calling `mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` to validate the configuration. This fails with an unmapped *Item* property.

While it is possible to ignore all properties starting with *Item* using

```cs
this.AddGlobalIgnore("Item")
```

inside the Profile, I'd rather not use such a general way to ignore it, especially since the first parameter is labeled *propertyNameStartingWith* - this would suggest to me, that other properties such as *ItemWithSuffix* might be ignored as well.

Another strategy I tried to employ is to use an explicit ignore on a property. Using the expression notation fails, due to compiler errors:

```cs
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest[], opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```

Adding an arbitrary index to the expression fails with another error, so that does not seem to be a viable solution as well:

```cs
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest[0], opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```

In this case the error notes, that we may not map to child property.

When using the member name syntax, there are some different errors.

```cs
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```

In this case it fails with the following message:

**Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Double get_Item(Int32)' (Parameter 'property')**

Using `[]` or `Item[]` fails with a missing property notification.

The last strategy I employed was using the *ForAllMembers* call. This succeeds, however, I'm wondering if there is a better solution to handle this logic which allows using a specific mapping logic for a single member.

```cs
CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForAllMembers(x =>
    {
        if (x.DestinationMember.Name == "Item")
        {
            x.Ignore();
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Item" works. A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I noticed after running it in my test environment once more. It actually only fails, if a .ReverseMap() is after the .ForMember("Item", opt => opt.Ignore()) so that should solve my issue. My original code had the .ReverseMap() included, but I omitted it when writing the question. My bad :(

Comment: So this took me far too long to uncover. I definitely consider this a [POLA Violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)